How to Efficiently Use std::variant for Error Handling in C++?
I've recently started exploring the use of std::variant in modern C++ (C++17 and later) to handle errors and return values simultaneously from functions, somewhat similar to Rust's Result type. I understand the basic usage of std::variant, but I'm looking for efficient and elegant patterns specifically tailored for error handling.
Here is what I've tried so far:
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

using Result = std::variant<std::string, int>;

Result computeValue(int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return "Negative input error";
    }
    return x * 2;
}

void handleResult(const Result& result) {
    std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << arg << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Computed value: " << arg << std::endl;
        }
    }, result);
}

int main() {
    Result res1 = computeValue(10);
    Result res2 = computeValue(-1);
    handleResult(res1);
    handleResult(res2);
    return 0;
}


I'm currently looking for feedback on the following:

Efficiency considerations when using std::variant in this manner.
Any potential pitfalls or improvements that can be made to this pattern.
How does this approach compare to using exceptions or other traditional error-handling methods in terms of performance and code clarity?

I would appreciate any insights or examples of best practices when using std::variant for error handling.

If you can use C++23, there is std::expected which is designed for that purpose.

Take a look on example in doc. This version with "overload" IMHO is much more readable and nice.

I would not do it like this anyway, you mix result with presentation (the english text for an internal error).
enum class ComputeError { None, NegativeInput }; and then struct  ComputeValueResult { ComputeValueError error; int value; }; And then in handle result you can use the enum value to create a string representation and in other situations you can use the enum value for branching in your business logic.


Efficiency considerations when using std::variant in this manner.

Because you have to visit on the happy path, on many platforms it will be less performant than using exceptions, which can be near-zero overhead when not thrown.

Any potential pitfalls or improvements that can be made to this pattern.

std::string is a fairly common type. What happens if you have a string operation that could fail?
You probably want to create a specific Error type, even if it is just
struct Error {
    std::string what;
};

It would also be nice to "lift" operations on int into the Result type:
template <typename UnaryOperation>
Result transform(UnaryOperation op, Result input) -> Result {
    return std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
    using T = decltype(arg);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, Error>) {
        return std::forward<T>(arg);
    } else {
        return op(std::forward<T>(arg));
    }, input);
}

template <typename BinaryOperation>
Result transform(BinaryOperation op, Result lhs, Result rhs) -> Result {
    return std::visit([](auto&& left, auto&& right) {
    using L = decltype(left);
    using R = decltype(right);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<L>, Error> && std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<R>, Error>) {
        return Error{ std::forward<L>(left).what + std::forward<R>(right).what };
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<L>, Error>){
        return std::forward<L>(left);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<R>, Error>){
        return std::forward<R>(right);
    } else {
        return op(std::forward<L>(left), std::forward<R>(right));
    }, lhs, rhs);
}

